# Getting feature class names within dataset with vb.net and ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, visual-studio

I am totally new to arcobjects. I want to get the feature class names withın a dataset and add them to a listbox.  I was able to get the dataset names but i do not know how to iterate through the feature class names within these datasets.

Public Sub GetWorkspace()

```
    Dim pEnumGxObj As ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IEnumGxObject
    Dim pFCFilter As New ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.GxFilterWorkspaces
    Dim pGxDatabase As ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxDatabase2
    Dim pGxDialog As New ESRI.ArcGIS.CatalogUI.GxDialog
    Dim pGxObject As ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxObject
    Dim pWorkspace As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspace

    pGxDialog.ObjectFilter = pFCFilter

    If Not pGxDialog.DoModalOpen(My.ArcMap.Application.hWnd, pEnumGxObj) Then Exit Sub

    pGxObject = pEnumGxObj.Next

    If pGxObject Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Try
        If TypeOf pGxObject Is ESRI.ArcGIS.Catalog.IGxDatabase2 Then
            pGxDatabase = pGxObject
            pWorkspace = pGxDatabase.Workspace
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(pWorkspace.PathName)
        Else
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("This is likely a shapefile workspace")
        End If


        Dim pEnumDSName = pWorkspace.DatasetNames(esriDatasetType.esriDTAny)


        Dim pSdeDSName = pEnumDSName.Next
        While Not pSdeDSName Is Nothing
            ListBox1.Items.Add(pSdeDSName.Name)
            pSdeDSName = pEnumDSName.Next
        End While


    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "GetWorkspace")

    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to iterate the datasets to get his containing feature classes. Like this:

```
While Not pSdeDSName Is Nothing
    Dim pEnumDataset = pSdeDSName.Subsets
    Dim pSubset = pEnumDataset.Next()
    While Not pSubset Is Nothing
        If pSubset.Type = ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.esriDatasetType.esriDTFeatureClass Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(pSubset.Name)
        End If
    End While
End While
```

The code is not tested, I'm used to C#, but you get the idea.